# QHash удаление указателя

Tags: c++, qt

Передаю в качестве аргумента функции указатель на хэш указателей:

```
void function(QHash<int, QHash<int, SomeClass *>*> *someparams)
{
    delete someparams;
}
```

Как корректно удалить указатель чтобы не было утечки памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void function(QHash<int, QHash<int, SomeClass *>*> *someparams)
{
    if(someparams != nullptr) {
        for(QHash<int, SomeClass *>* valueHash : someparams->values()) {
            if(valueHash != nullptr) {
                for(SomeClass* valueClass : valueHash ->values()) {
                    if(valueClass != nullptr) delete valueClass;
                }
                valueHash->clear();
                delete valueHash;
            }
        }
        someparams->clear();
        delete someparams;
    }
}
```